# How to edit jupyter notebook shortcuts

Tags: jupyter-notebook, keyboard-shortcuts

Jupyter notebooks have a convenient means to `edit shortcuts` - by pressing *H* for help there is a button for it:

[image]

And here is the dialog to make the updates:

[image]

The question here is: when pressing `add shortcut` we apparently have a free form text field to enter the shortcut:

[image]

But whatever combination I put in actually causes some _system_wide_ kind of behavior to kick-in e.g. `Command-R` causes Jupyter to do something wacky, and I tried a couple of others.  Is there another way to enter these?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried clicking on that link: **details of defining keyboard shortcuts**?

That gives some general tips on creating new shortcuts.

Your example might not work because you would want to use "Cmd-R" instead of "Command-R". Though, in my operating system, "Cmd-r" already does something(reloads the page).  So whatever combination or sequence you choose, I'd make sure it doesn't already do something before using it as a shortcut.

Once you type into the field, are you clicking the "+" button to the right?  If you click on that, it should then show if it's been set, and you can verify it set it to what you wanted.  If you don't click the "+" button, it will have no effect.

Good luck!